# What is the difference between fetch and nuxtServerInit in Nuxt.js?

Tags: nuxt.js

According to the Nuxt documentation these methods are used to pre-fill store before page is served.

In what cases should I use `fetch` and in what cases - `nuxtServerInit`?

Answer (score 7):

I think of `nuxtServerInit` as the place to go if I need to make requests that prefetch options that are used in all the App, languages, configaration values, input options, etc...

`fetch` &`asyncData` instead fire both on the client and server once that pages gets rendered.

That means that `fetch` & `asyncData` will fire every time the component is matched by the router and `nuxtServerInit` only once, at the beginning, on the server, and never again.

Comment: What if you had a list of products that are only on 1 page? Eg 1 page for shirts, 1 page for jeans etc. would you just use fetch on the page for this?

Comment: Looks like a `fetch/asyncData` to me. You can reuse the same component for /shirts and /jeans and then in asyncData you fetch your products from the API based on the param of the $route

Comment: Ok great....so I have some global settings like sales=true that I can get with axios on nuxtServerInit, my products lists with axios and fetch/async and then my detail pages with axios and asyncData with route params to the api?

Answer (score 4):

Use `nuxtServerInit` if you need to fill the store with specific data from the very beginning, no matter which page was accessed first.

Use `fetch/asyncData` when a specific page is accessed and you need to fill the vuex store (or the page `data` object) for this page specifically.

Answer (score 1):

**nuxtServerInit**: it is used to fetch some data you work with a lot (such as userInfo in the session), only once, then you can use it in all the components. So, you don't have to constantly reach out to the server. Moreover, it is an action in the store provided by Vuex, so it'll dispatch automatically by Vuex.

**fetch/asyncData**: they are executed before rendering the page both server-side (when you refresh the page) and client-side (when you click around and route to the page). However, **fetch** used only to fill the store (you can get the data from the store in computed), and **asynchData** used to set the component data (you can fill the store in created hook).

References:
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action and 
https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch